# Overriding standard edit button in community cloud doesn't work even though all settings are fine (and other buttons overriding works fine)

Tags: community, lightning-community, button-overrides

Something weird is happening in our community site.

We have the New and Edit standard button overridden for our custom object, so it can be edited in our custom component.

[image]

Everything works fine, but not in our community cloud.

We have a related list that shows all records for such object, filtered for owned records:

[image]

When I click on New, everything works fine. The standard button is overridden and I create my new record in my custom component, as it should be.

But when I click on edit, that doesn't happen! No overriding for the edit button and no component popping up; I get the standard edit layout instead.

Why does this happen? Settings are fine, overriding is correctly enabled for the community site.

[image]

It's very weird as it works for a button, but doesn't for another... and it only happens in the community cloud sites.

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Comment: Does it show any error?

Comment: No errors, it just pops up the standard editing layout instead of the custom component. Should havew specified this, sorry, gonna edit now

Comment: still facing the issue? @robruf